# Handling the error in case of exceeding the OpenAI Rate Limit

Tags: openai-api

I need help with resolving the OpenAI Rate Limit Error. This error appears only occasionally. The function below is responsible for data vectorization. How can I incorporate logic into it so that if a Rate Limit Error occurs, the script waits for 60 seconds and then retries? Is there a better approach to handling this? I'm uncertain about the best way to proceed.

I am going to need a retry loop, e.g. "while True:" so that it retries after sleep, then I probably also want an async sleep in there. I would have expected some await calls in there, given this is an async function, but that's a separate issue
I want the retry at a lower level so that you keep any partial results genereated prior to the rate limit error.

The function responsible for vectorization:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 512
@app.get("/vectorize-data", status_code=200)
async def vectorize_data():
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE, chunk_overlap=0)
    raw_data = db.load_data_documentation()
    raw_data2 = db.load_data2_documentation()

    docs_data = text_splitter.split_documents(vectorizer.create_multiple_data_documents(raw_data))
    docs_data2 = text_splitter.split_documents(vectorizer.create_multiple_data2_documents(raw_data2))

    documents = [*docs_data, *docs_data2]
    start_time = time.time()

    # Iterate over the documents in chunks
    for i in range(0, len(documents), CHUNK_SIZE):
        while True:
            try:
                Milvus.from_documents(
                    documents[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE],
                    embeddings,
                    collection_name=VECTOR_DB_NAME,
                    connection_args=CONNECTION_ARGS,
                )
                break
            except HTTPException as http_error:
                logger.exception("HTTP ERROR: {0}", str(http_error.detail))
                if http_error.status_code == 429:
                    await asyncio.sleep(60)
                else:
                    raise
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception("ERROR: {0}", str(e))
                raise

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return {
        "total_time_s": elapsed_time,
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

1. Do not catch all exceptions, just the one that relates to the rate-limit
2. Do not rely on the error-message to determine what is wrong, use the
   status-code
3. I do not know what kind of service you are
   programming, but a response-time of a minute or several will cause
   trouble in a lot of systems as clients (browsers or other services) will think your
   service is unresponsive.
4. Note that limits apply not only per minute but also per day: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/overview. Do not wait for 20 hours by doing a new request every minute. Failing the request completely is preferable in such situations.

Comment: How to catch the error code? What should this function look like then? :( I'm more of a data scientist than an engineer and I'm not very proficient in software engineering.
Point 3 and 4 is not a problem. "if http_error.status_code == 429:"  is a good solution?

Comment: @tbone Instead of `catch Exception` you write `catch <SpecificException>`. You can also have multiple catch-blocks for one try-block if you want to handle a specific exception but also have a generic failure-case. Your way to check the status-code looks good.

Comment: @tbone This looks fine to me. And I now realize that your endpoint initiates a long task so you do not worry about what the extra minute does to your client. If you run into troubles with the length of the task, change the endpoint to return immediately with an ID that the client can use to check the status of that long-running-task (using another endpoint)